# How to change the Encoding? (Greek- ISO-8859-7)

Tags: code

Can I choose that encoding instead of the default? I can open a file with similar apps. If I open the same file with Scratch, it displays non-readable characters. I cannot find the appropriate setting for changing that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check that locale it's installed. From terminal, execute

```
cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED | grep 8859-7
```

You can see an output like this:

```
el_GR ISO-8859-7
el_CY ISO-8859-7
```

If you want to configure your system with the first locale *(el_GR ISO-8859-7)* you must reconfigure your environment. Try from terminal:

```
localectl set-locale "LANG=el_GR.ISO-8859-7"
localectl set-locale "LANGUAGE=el_GR.ISO-8859-7"
localectl set-locale "LC_ALL=el_GR.ISO-8859-7"
```

Now, you must generate your desired locale:

```
locale-gen el_GR.ISO-8859-7
```

And finally:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.
I transformed file encoding from Windows-1251 to UTF-8 by this command in terminal:
iconv -f Windows-1251 -t UTF-8 inputfile.txt  > outputfile.txt